# Windows 10- In eclipse (Oxygen version), createProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

Operating system - Windows 10

Error as soon as the application is launched in eclipse(Oxygen version)

> Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory
>   "C:\PPM\PPML10_41A"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or
>   extension is too long.

Have tried JDK instead of JRE.
Have tried different version of jre 1.8 too.
Have tried placing it in other directory like  "D:\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\javaw.exe".

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a current version of Eclipse (2018-12)? If yes, what is the command line (in the run configuration click _Show Command Line_). On Windows the length of a command line call is limited. For many dependencies, Eclipse uses the trick of a dynamically generated JAR. But this trick does not work when the command line call becomes too long because of other arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you made your own build file rather than the [Proj] ->  [Gen Javadocs] thing, you can add useexternalfile=“yes” to the javadoc tags; I’m pretty sure this should help but I’m still in bed in my phone, so I’ll check up later to see if it didn’t.

Comment: exactly how am i supposed to do that, i mean how do i add 'useexternalfile=“yes” to the javadoc tags' in eclipse . Can you pls help me with the above.